# Fail to install peewee under WinPython

Tags: python, peewee

I am trying to `pip install peewee` on Windows using WinPython (2 or 3) and the installation chokes on the absence of the 'sqlite3.h' header file. I have copied the file from the sqlite website and then the installation fails on an undefined reference to 'init_sqlite_ext'. At this point I gave up. Any tips on installing peewee with WinPython?

Comment: `init_sqlite_ext` is the wrong `PyMODINIT_FUNC` to call on Python 3. It should be `PyInit__sqlite_ext`. Consider reporting the issue at https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues

Answer (score -1):

Try version 2.7.2, which doesn't build the sqlite extension by default:

```
    pip install peewee==2.7.2
```

Hope this advice will help you.